# Как записать каждый элемент списка в строку csv Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как записать каждый элемент списка в отдельную ячейку в одну строку. Есть список:
`a = [1, 2, 3, 4, "fdg"]`

Если так делать:

```
with open("1.csv", "a") as p:
    pr = csv.writer(p, delimiter = ";", lineterminator = '\n')
    for i in a:
        pr.writerow([i])
```

то будет все в один столбец записываться, если так делать:

```
with open("1.csv", "a") as p:
    pr = csv.writer(p, delimiter = ";", lineterminator = '\n')
    pr.writerow([а])
```

то все элементы запишутся в одну ячейку.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: может `.writerow(a)`?

Comment: точно, тупанул) спасибо